# Show that a matrix is not diagonalizable over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I have a matrix: $$\
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 2 \\
   1 & 2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$ which I need to show that it cannot be diagonalized over the finite field $\mathbb{F_3}$.

I have computed the characteristic polynomial. It is: $$p(x)=x^2-4x+2.$$

Obviously in $\mathbb{F_3}$, $4=1.$  Hence, $$p(x)=x^2-x+2.$$ But $p(x)$ does not split into linear factors in $\mathbb{F_3}$. Is this the proof?

Comment: Completing the proof would require something about why not having any linear factors would mean it's not diagonalizable. Assuming you do know why, you'll have to use your own judgement whether or not you think it would be appropriate to include that part of the argument. Given that this sounds like homework, that probably means whether you think that piece of knowledge is part of what you're being tested on, or if you think it's a piece of knowledge that you're expected to know implicitly (and think it's not bad style to omit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** A few basics about reduction:
if a matrix is diagonalizable, it has eigenvalues. There are necessarily roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: That is what I was trying to say. $p(x)$ does not have any root over $\mathbb{F_3}$. Is this a correct way to conclude?

Comment: @math See Hurkyl's comment. Some people will consider that enough, some will want more. It certainly is correct, but you might need more detail.

Comment: @math it seems enough to me.