# $2 \times 2$ matrices in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ that are diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

How would one find all matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ that are diagonalizable? What about in $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$? For the first question, I have tried caseworking on the possible arrangements of eigenvalues 0 and 1, noting that the algebraic multiplicity of 0 and 1 must sum to 2. I also tried taking the characteristic polynomial of an arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, but both of these methods did not result in anything. Is there a quick way to do this without trying every matrix?

Comment: You always have to calculate the characteristic polynomial and investigate the eigenvalues and their algebraic and geometric multiplicities. In case of $2\times 2$-matrices you can do a case distinction. Have a look at some [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025133/show-that-a-matrix-is-not-diagonalizable-over-a-finite-field). For a full answer see [this thesis](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjd4K75vab-AhWo9rsIHao1AtoQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdigital.wpi.edu%2Fdownloads%2F08612r740%3Flocale%3Den&usg=AOvVaw0ivIRqd44Bk28Jh3xkjR35).

Comment: What's stopping you from using the exact same approach as $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Do you mean diagonalizable over the base field or diagonalizable over a field extension?

Comment: According to Dietrich's link, there are in general $\frac{q^4 - q^2 + 2q}{2}$ diagonalizable matrices in $M_2(\Bbb F_q)$. That means a total of $8$ for $q = 2$ and $39$ for $q = 3$.